# Why indexOnly==false

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with index:

```
{
    "UserId" : 1,
    "ShareId" : 1,
    "ParentId" : 1,
    "DeletedDate" : 1
}
```

If I making query:

```
db.Files.find({ "UserId" : ObjectId("5450d837f32a1e098c844e2a"),
    "ShareId" : ObjectId("5450d879f32a1e098c844e94"),
    "ParentId" : ObjectId("5450d8af6a092a0b74a44026"),
    "DeletedDate":null},
    {_id:0, ShareId:1}).explain()
```

output says that `"indexOnly" : false:`

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor UserId_1_ShareId_1_ParentId_1_DeletedDate_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 2120,
"nscannedObjects" : 2120,
"nscanned" : 2120,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2318,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 2320,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 21,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 42,
"indexBounds" : {
    "UserId" : [ 
        [ 
            ObjectId("5450d837f32a1e098c844e2a"), 
            ObjectId("5450d837f32a1e098c844e2a")
        ]
    ],
    "ShareId" : [ 
        [ 
            ObjectId("5450d879f32a1e098c844e94"), 
            ObjectId("5450d879f32a1e098c844e94")
        ]
    ],
    "ParentId" : [ 
        [ 
            ObjectId("5450d8af6a092a0b74a44026"), 
            ObjectId("5450d8af6a092a0b74a44026")
        ]
    ],
    "DeletedDate" : [ 
        [ 
            null, 
            null
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "mongowecntprod:27017",
"filterSet" : false,
"stats" : {
    "type" : "PROJECTION",
    "works" : 2124,
    "yields" : 21,
    "unyields" : 21,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "advanced" : 2120,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needFetch" : 2,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "works" : 2124,
            "yields" : 21,
            "unyields" : 21,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 2120,
            "needTime" : 1,
            "needFetch" : 2,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "children" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "FETCH",
                    "works" : 2124,
                    "yields" : 21,
                    "unyields" : 21,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 2120,
                    "needTime" : 1,
                    "needFetch" : 2,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "forcedFetches" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 2120,
                    "children" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : "IXSCAN",
                            "works" : 2121,
                            "yields" : 21,
                            "unyields" : 21,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "advanced" : 2120,
                            "needTime" : 1,
                            "needFetch" : 0,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : "{ UserId: 1, ShareId: 1, ParentId: 1, DeletedDate: 1 }",
                            "isMultiKey" : 0,
                            "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['UserId']: [ObjectId('5450d837f32a1e098c844e2a'), ObjectId('5450d837f32a1e098c844e2a')], field #1['ShareId']: [ObjectId('5450d879f32a1e098c844e94'), ObjectId('5450d879f32a1e098c844e94')], field #2['ParentId']: [ObjectId('5450d8af6a092a0b74a44026'), ObjectId('5450d8af6a092a0b74a44026')], field #3['DeletedDate']: [null, null]",
                            "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0,
                            "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                            "matchTested" : 0,
                            "keysExamined" : 2120,
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

but if I making query without DeletedDate:

```
db.Files.find({ "UserId" : ObjectId("5450d837f32a1e098c844e2a"),
    "ShareId" : ObjectId("5450d879f32a1e098c844e94"),
    "ParentId" : ObjectId("5450d8af6a092a0b74a44026")},
    {_id:0, ShareId:1}).explain()
```

then `"indexOnly"` is `true`.

How I can change first query to making `indexOnly=true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a simple example that will hopefully demonstrate what you're seeing when you are querying for a field being null:

```javascript
db.nullexplain.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5456759f51a9d5271dc55bba"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545675a251a9d5271dc55bbb"), "a" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545675a551a9d5271dc55bbc") }

db.nullexplain.ensureIndex({a:1})

db,nullexplain.count({a:1}).count()
1
db.nullexplain.count({a:null}).count()
2
```

Do you see the issue?   When "a" is present and explicitly set to null, it's indexed as null.
When "a" is not present in the document, it's also indexed as null.

When you query:

```javascript
db.nullexplain.find({a:null},{_id:0,a:1})
{ "a" : null }
{  }
```

How can we derive from the index only whether the return document should have the field "a" set to null or if the field should not be present at all?
The answer is we cannot and therefore we must examine the document itself.

```javascript
db.nullexplain.find({a:null},{_id:0,a:1}).explain()
{
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 2,
"nscannedObjects" : 3,
"nscanned" : 3,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 3,
"server" : "Asyas-MacBook-Pro.local:27017",
"filterSet" : false
}
```

Hope this helps you understand why querying for `DeletedDate:null` has to check the document and cannot be answered from the index.

Comment: @serenesat included the essential info. Hope it's looks good now